# Win8/XAML Sort CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I am trying to sort my CollectionViewSource. I have tried SortDescriptions, , however it gives an unknown member error(even after adding references)

```
    <common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>

<common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>

    <!--
        Collection of grouped items displayed by this page, bound to a set
        of the complete item list because items in groups cannot be virtualized
    -->
    <!--Replace d:Source... with the following to obtain data from the actual Azure Service-->
    <!--Source="{Binding ItemGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=ViewModels:ItemsShowcaseViewModel}}"-->
    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="groupedItemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding ItemGroups}"
        d:Source="{Binding ItemGroups, Source={d:DesignInstance IsDesignTimeCreatable=True, Type=sampleData:ItemsShowcaseSampleData}}" IsSourceGrouped="True" 
        >


    </CollectionViewSource>


</common:LayoutAwarePage.Resources>
```

Comment: look at this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/527686/A-WinRT-CollectionView-class-with-Filtering-and-So

Answer (score 1):

Sorting isn't built into `CollectionViewSource` in WinRT/XAML. You need to sort your data in your data/view-model.